# How to run a command line through a button React javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to run a command line through a button on my react app. I can't seem to figure it out, I tried using href= but still can't find a solution.

I would just like the button to run a command line opening a website like "www.google.com".

```
<Button
color='green'
active={true}
label='Clear Selection'
href="CMD.exe"
/>
```

I expect the terminal to open but nothing seems to happen except `http://localhost:3000/CMD.exe` running.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, nothing you put in makes sense.
What do you want to open using a javascript button?
What does CMD.exe (windows console) mean in all this?

Comment: It would be extremely dangerous if websites could run arbitrary commands on the client's machines. You will need to cooperate with a server component for this.

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner in javascript.

Comment: What I would like to do is click on a button on my interface, this button will then pass a command line through the terminal

Comment: @MARKV Please make your requirement clear. If Your requirement is just to open some website on button click then you don't need a Command to do it. Why do you want to access CLI through your react app, what is that you are exactly looking for?